# PostgreSQL : Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting error

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, celery

Celery is not able to connect to PostgreSQL in my docker service and getting this error

```
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
celery_1       |        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
celery_1       |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

**while PostgreSQL working fine for database and I am able to perform actions** its just in case of celery .

I have now 2 cases  in this celery service

```
  celery:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: celery -A sampleproject worker -l info
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    - POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}
    - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}

    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/

    depends_on:
     - database
     - app
     - redis
```

when I pass all **PostgreSQL variables** in celery environment its working. while I delete them its not working . why its happening ? and how I can resolve this ? so that I can run celery with proper way

Answer (score 0):

Found this while searching for the same. I'll share my solution for anyone else that finds this.

For me, the issue was that `${POSTGRES_HOST}` host was set to `localhost`. It should be set to `database`.